# Filetype inheritance

Tags: filetype, ftplugin

I know that it's not very common, but there are few cases in which I would really like to inherit the configurations for one filetype in another.

*Example:* whatever I set for `sh` I would like to inherit in `zsh` and `bash`

I know that it might be dangerous, since I won't be able to set any `sh` specific variable any longer, but in few cases (like this), I don't believe this should be a problem.

For the time being the best way I found it's to use:

```
runtime! ftplugin/sh.vim
```

are you aware of anything better?

Comment: This might not work in every case, but you can have a buffer with multiple filetypes (I exploit this for https://github.com/benknoble/wiki-md): `set filetype=sh.bash.zsh`

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble . I believe it's quite doing the job. The only thing I can imagine that it's not covered is the `ftdetect` itself: if I have custom rules for `zsh` the wanted behavior would be to extend filetype also for them, but maybe it's just a matter of sorting the commands. Can you point me the reference for multiple filetypes? I cannot find it in the docs...

Comment: @Annibale See the part under [`:help 'filetype'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ft%27) that begins "When a dot"

Comment: @Rich thank you, I was looking to [`:help filetype`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype) unfortunately...

Comment: @Annibale figuring out how to find things in the `:help` is an art in and of itself ;)